# Getting information from previous click viewfipper in android

Tags: android, viewflipper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to check previous value in android of viewflipper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515802/how-to-check-previous-value-in-android-of-viewflipper)

I have 4 viewflipper. so every viewflipper has own information. If i am first time click **viewflipper3** which have **100( or any information)** . so after clicking, next time i click **viewflipper1**,so i have to need that current **viewfliper1** now that 100 value from **viewflipper 3**. so how to get that information in current viewflipper from previous clickable viewflipper.