# How to replace a view with another in ViewFlipper

Tags: android, view, viewflipper

My app contains a ViewFlipper with more images. It is autoflipping the images using some animations. I want that when a certain image is displayed, ViewFlipper to stop slipping, the image to be replace with another image, and then ViewFlipper to start again flipping. I spent a lot of time with this but it is not getting work. I tried to replace the view and add a new view but the app not works how it should work. Has anyone worked with ViewFlipper? Does anyone know how to replace a view with a new one?

Here is my code :

```
vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.details);
vf.setFlipInterval(Integer.valueOf(3 * 1000));

//populate the ViewFlipper with images

vf.setOutAnimation(animFlipOutNext);
vf.setInAnimation(animFlipInNext);
vf.setAutoStart(true);
```

The Animations I used :

```
animFlipInNext = AnimationUtils
                .loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_left_in);
        animFlipInNext.setDuration(2000);
        animFlipInNext.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                System.out.println("AnimStart- LeftIn" + " Will be displayed "
                        + vf.getDisplayedChild());
                imageName = images.listFiles();

                for (int i = 0; i < imageName.length; i++) {
                    if (vf.getCurrentView().getTag().toString()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(imageName[i].getName())) {
                        System.out.println("begin  " + imageName[i].getName());
                        vf.stopFlipping();

                    } else
                        System.out.println("NUNUNU");

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                System.out.println("AnimRepeat-LeftIn");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                System.out.println("Anim end " + vf.getDisplayedChild());
                for (int i = 0; i < imageName.length; i++) {
                    if (vf.getCurrentView().getTag().toString()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(imageName[i].getName())) {
                        System.out.println("begin  " + imageName[i].getName());
                        videoname = imageName[i].getName().replace("1.jpg", "");
                        System.out.println("VideoName este " + videoname
                                + ".mp4");

                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment
                                .getExternalStorageDirectory()

                        + "/Images" + "/" + "23Video1.jpg");
                        img = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
                        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                        int nr = vf.getDisplayedChild();
                        System.out.println("nr view "+nr);

                        vf.removeViewAt(nr);

                        vf.addView(img, nr,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                        vf.setDisplayedChild(nr);
                        vf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        img=null;
                        //vf.setDisplayedChild(nr);

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        animFlipOutNext = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.push_left_out);
        animFlipOutNext.setDuration(2000);

        animFlipInPrevious = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.push_right_in);
        animFlipInPrevious.setDuration(2000);

        animFlipOutPrevious = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.push_right_out);
        animFlipOutPrevious.setDuration(2000);
```

I try to replace the view on `onAnimationEnd` method. Please help.. Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

ViewFlipper has methods showNext and showPrevious by whose we can change currently displayed child, to get current displayed child, use getDisplayedChild it will return index of currently displayed child.

Just use following method to display nth element:

```
private void display(int n)
{
    int index=viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild();
    while(n<index)
    {
       viewFlipper.showPrevious();
       index--;
    }
    while(n>index)
    {
         viewFlipper.showNext();
         index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I use getDisplayedChild ro get the index of current displayed child.  The problem is with replacing the view. the new image is not added to the viewflipper

Answer (score 0):

Ihave done just like you problem without animation only replacing viewflipper. you can put different animation on animation properties. Put this type of xml layout.

```
 <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/vf1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="3dp">
            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/RLF1" android:background="@drawable/block_purpal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/RLB1" android:gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/block_purpal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1"
                     android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ViewFlipper>
```

Set Delay time:

```
    private static final long DELAYTIME = 1000;
```

Put on clicklistener of view flipper

```
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = 1;
            delayHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, DELAYTIME);

            vFilpper1.showNext();
```

finally add this :
          public Handler delayHandler = new Handler() {

```
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        super.handleMessage(message);

        switch (message.what) {
        case 1:
            try {
                vFilpper1.showPrevious();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

    so on other viewflipper..
```

Also Visit it [Documention](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) 
if you thing this is not better idea then go to :

[how to check previous value in android of viewflipper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515802/how-to-check-previous-value-in-android-of-viewflipper)

http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-view-filpper-and-sliding-drawer/